# Adding attributes to ahref button using the link already present there

Tags: javascript, java, php

I'm trying to add attributes to link taken from ahref html tag, please can anybody guide me that what am I doing wrong in this?

link will be taken from ahref tag and lang and currency from dropdowns and then the final link will be
"link+"index.php?lang="+lang+"&currency="+currency;"

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var saveclass = null;

function onChangeHandler() {
  const lang = document.querySelector('#lang').value;
  const currency = document.querySelector('#currency').value;
  var link=document.querySelector('#theButton')..getAttribute('href');
  var strLink = link+"index.php?lang="+lang+"&currency="+currency;
  document.querySelector('#theButton').setAttribute('href', strLink);
  
}


onChangeHandler();
document.querySelector('#lang').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
document.querySelector('#currency').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);




});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="price_billing.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<select name="" id="lang">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="currency">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
  </select>

  <a href="https://alpha.com" id="theButton">Click</a>

  <select name="" id="lang">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="currency">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
  </select>

  <a href="https://alpha.com" id="theButton">Click</a>
  

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a crack at this. Looks like you have an extra period [.] in front of getAttribute.

Working code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var saveclass = null;

function onChangeHandler() {
  const lang = document.querySelector('#lang').value;
  const currency = document.querySelector('#currency').value;
  var link=document.querySelector('#theButton').getAttribute('href');
  var strLink = link+"/index.php?lang="+lang+"&currency="+currency;
  document.querySelector('#theButton').setAttribute('href', strLink);

}

document.querySelector('#lang').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
document.querySelector('#currency').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);

}); 
</script>

<select name="" id="lang">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  </select>

  <select name="" id="currency">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
  </select>

  <a href="https://alpha.com" id="theButton">Click</a>
```

I also took out the extra onChangeHandler(); because you already have change listeners running the function.

While this ***technically*** works, I don't recommend it. If a user keeps changing options, it keeps appending the new URL. Examples below:

https://alpha.com/index.php?lang=French&currency=USD
https://alpha.com/index.php?lang=French&currency=USD/index.php?lang=French&currency=EUR
https://alpha.com/index.php?lang=French&currency=USD/index.php?lang=French&currency=EUR/index.php?lang=Spanish&currency=EUR
https://alpha.com/index.php?lang=French&currency=USD/index.php?lang=French&currency=EUR/index.php?lang=Spanish&currency=EUR/index.php?lang=Spanish&currency=MXN
https://alpha.com/index.php?lang=French&currency=USD/index.php?lang=French&currency=EUR/index.php?lang=Spanish&currency=EUR/index.php?lang=Spanish&currency=MXN/index.php?lang=English&currency=MXN
https://alpha.com/index.php?lang=French&currency=USD/index.php?lang=French&currency=EUR/index.php?lang=Spanish&currency=EUR/index.php?lang=Spanish&currency=MXN/index.php?lang=English&currency=MXN/index.php?lang=English&currency=USD

It would be better to change the URL after users are 100% sure of their options instead of on every single change.